# path finding: calculating the optimal path, where “optimal” means maximum distance within a given time

Tags: algorithm, distance, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but here's my problem:

I have a large set of points, where each point represents a coordinate. I need to develop an algorithm that calculates which points to visit in order to maximise the total distance travelled within a certain time span (e.g., 24 hours). For each path between two points I know the distance and the maximum speed.

In addition, there's a constraint. Each path can only be travelled twice (so, up and down is possible but then both points cannot be used again).

My problem is: I don't know where to start. I've looked at some pathfinding algorithms (eg Dijkstra's), but they're all to find the least distance whereas I need to find the maximum distance!

Comment: Keep researching. Some path-finding algorithms can easily be modified to maximize the distance (especially if all weights are positive/negative). Wikipedia is actually an excellent resource for pathfinding.

Comment: Multiply all distances by `-1` and then find the minimum distance

Comment: The problem here is not just about finding the maximum distance, but also to find the maximum distance one can travel within a limited time-frame. More-over, some algorithms like Dijkstra's don't work with negative costs. Yes there are other algorithms like Belman Ford's or Floyd Warshall's etc, but they can't be applied as is.

Comment: @blgt this technique cannot be used with all algorithms (I mean dijkstra's cannot use it)

Comment: Is the time needed to travel between two points proportional to the distance between them?  If so, then **it doesn't matter which points you visit.**

Answer (score 0):

If the time is integer and not too big, you can use dynamic programming.

create dp[pos][t]

which means currently in time t, you are in positon pos, the maximun distance you can achieve.

then your answer is the maximun value of {dp[destinatin][valid_time]}.

dp[][] can be calculated like dijkstra or spfa algorithm.

Hope this can help you a bit.